# Does my proof of the Sequential Criterion for Limits work?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I'm attempting to prove the Sequential Criterion of Limits working off of this iteration:

> Suppose $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is a cluster point of $A$, and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}.$ Then the following are equivalent:
>
> $(1)$ $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L.$
>
> $(2)$ For all sequences $x_n\in A\setminus\{c\}$ with $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=c$, we have that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L.$

Here is my proof below. Starting where I have noted **, I am aware there is another solution where we set $\delta=1/n$ and construct a sequence $x_n\in A\setminus\{c\}$ with $0<|x_n-c|<1/n.$ I'm wondering if my solution also works.

**Proof:** $(1)\implies(2):$ Since $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L,$ given $\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$ such that if $x\in A$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$ Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $A\setminus\{c\}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=c.$ Then there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough so that if $n\geq N,$ $0<|x_n-c|<\delta$. Therefore, $|f(x_n)-L|<\epsilon$, meaning $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L.$

$\neg(1)\implies\neg(2):$ Since $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\neq L,$ there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $\delta>0,$ $\exists x_\delta\in A$ with $0<|x_\delta-c|<\delta$ and $|f(x_\delta)-L|\geq\epsilon_0.$ **So then fix $\delta>0.$ Let $0<\delta_1<\delta.$ Then since $c$ is a cluster point of $A$, there exists $x_1\in A$ such that $0<|x_1-c|<\delta_1$ and $|f(x_1)-L|\geq \epsilon_0.$ Now let $0<\delta_2<\delta_1.$ By the same reasoning, $\exists x_2\in A$ such that $0<|x_2-c|<\delta_2$ and $|f(x_2)-L|\geq\epsilon_0.$ Repeat this process to obtain the sequence $x_n\in A\setminus\{c\}.$ We have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=c$ since $\delta>0$ is arbitrary and $|x_n-c|<\delta$ for all $n\geq 1.$ Additionally, given any $n\in\mathbb{N},$ $|f(x_n)-L|\geq\epsilon_0,$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\neq L.$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks good to me!